# Harmonic Analysis prove that a function is pseudometric

Tags: general-topology

Given that X is a vector space equipped with a semi norm $||.||_X$ one needs to show that $d(x,y)=\frac{||x-y||_X}{1+||x-y||_X}$ is a pseudometric on $X$.

I have a hard time figuring out why is $d_X(x,y)=d_X(y,x) $ as well as showing the triangle inequality for $d_X$ so would appreciate any help.

Comment: Caution ! $d(x,y)=\frac{||x-y||x}{1+||x-y||x}$ as it is written is meaningless because expression $||x-y||x $ cannot be neither in the denominator (you cannot divide by a vector...) nor in the numerator because $d$ is assumed to take real values...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I understand now: instead of a multiplication by little $x$, it is an indexation by a capital $X$ !!! Please change it by writing `\|x-y\|_X'...

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with harmonic analysis. I have changed this tag into "general topology" tag.

Comment: It is classical that for a "full-fleshed" distance $d$, $d':=\frac{d}{1+d}$ is itself a distance : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1073002