# This metrics $d_1(s, t)=\left | {s\over 1 +|s|}- {t\over 1 +|t|}\right| $ and $d_2(s,t)=|s-t|$ ar e equivalents?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, equivalent-metrics

In  several lists of exercises they affirm that these norms are equivalent: show that this metrics $d_1(s, t)= \left| {s\over 1 +|s|}- {t\over 1 +|t|}\right| $ and $d_2(s,t)=|s-t|$, with $t,s \in \mathbb{R}$, are equivalents.

I tried to show that equivalence
of metrics using this definition: for each $ s \in X$, there exist positive constants  $\alpha$  and $\beta$  such that, for every point $ t \in X $,
$$\alpha d_{2}(s, t) \leq d_{1}(s, t) \leq \beta d_{2}(s, t)$$.

Taking $X=\mathbb{R}$. I choose for example, $s=4$, if that equivalence of norms was truth must exists $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that, for every $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

$$\alpha |4-t|  \leq \left| {4\over 5}- {t\over 1 +|t|}\right| \leq \beta |4-t|$$.

also if $t\geqslant 0$, then
$$\alpha |4-t|  \leq \left| {4\over 5}- {t\over 1 +t}\right| \leq \beta |4-t|$$.
$$\alpha |4-t|  \leq  {|4-t|\over 5(1 +t)} \leq \beta |4-t|$$
$$5\alpha   \leq  {1\over (1 +t)} \leq 5 \beta $$
In this part, I can't find an $\alpha>0$ that satisfies, for all $t$ very big in $\mathbb{R}$.
Can I conclude that these metrics aren't equivalents. or how can I show that they are equivalents?

Comment: Also see the difference between Lipchitz equivalence and topological equivalence.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to have inequalities of the type $$\alpha d_{2}(s, t) \leq d_{1}(s, t) \leq \beta d_{2}(s, t)$$  simply because $d_1(s,t) \leq 1+1=2$ for all $s,t$ and $$\alpha |s-t| \leq d_{1}(s, t) \leq 2$$ cannot holds for all $s,t$.

Your definition of equivalent metrics is called strong equivalence and the two metrics you have are not equivalent in this sense.

Two metrics are (toplogically) equivalent if they have the same open sets. [This is different from strong equivalence]. According to this definition your metrics are indeed equivalent and this has been  proved many times on this site. I will let you search MSE for a proof.

Comment: No, his definition of equivalent metrics is not false. Simply, there is a missing adjective : in his case, it is **strong** equivalence whereas in your case it is **topological** equivalence. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics. See as well https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1073002/305862

Comment: @JeanMarie I have edited the answer for clarification. What OP is trying to prove is false.

Comment: Thanks now I understand